# Why is an interface in the sub class not released

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm facing the following situation and I'm wondering this code is leaking memory.
Let say I have the following interfaces and implementations:

```
type
ITools = interface
  function HelloWorld : String;
end;

IDatabase = interface
  function Query(AQuery : String) : String;
end;

IManager = interface
  procedure Execute;
end;

TDatabase = class(TInterfacedObject, IDatabase)
  strict private
    FTools : ITools;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Query(AQuery : String) : String;
end;

TTools = class(TInterfacedObject, ITools)
  strict private
    FDatabase : IDatabase;
  public
    constructor Create(ADatabase : IDatabase);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function HelloWorld : String;
end;

TManager = class(TInterfacedObject, IManager)
  strict private
    FDatabase : IDatabase;
  public
    constructor Create;
    procedure Execute;
end;
```

Now, if you create for example this:

```
procedure Example;
var 
  lExample : IManager;
begin
  lExample := TManager.Create;
  lExample.Execute;
  lExampe := nil; // Should not be necessary
end;
```

Where `FDatabase` from `TManager` is created as `TDatabase` and passed in to the constructor of `TTools`, so it has the same (?) object / interface in TTools as in TManager.
Then `lExample` leaks memory, because of the interfaces / objects in the sub class (`IDatabase`). Why isn't it the interface released? Or what do I don't understand of the Delphi fundamentals?

Comment: Question will be easy to answer once it is posed clearly.

Comment: You probably have a circular reference. See https://www.finalbuilder.com/resources/blogs/postid/410/weakrefence-in-delphi-solving-circular-interfac and http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/06/18/Circular-reference-and-zeroing-weak-pointers

Comment: Yes, there is a circular reference.  The Database has a **strong** reference to the Tools, which has a **strong** reference to the Database. Classic memory leak in a ref-counted system.  One of those references needs to be changed into a **weak** reference instead.  However, weak interface references were not supported yet in XE7, that was recently added in 10.1 Berlin (see http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2016-april-weak-unsafe-interface-references.html). In earlier versions, you have to resort to using `Pointer` and typecasts to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: See: http://blog.dummzeuch.de/2014/06/19/weak-references-or-why-you-should-enable-reportmemoryleaksonshutdown/ for a solution for XE7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't it the interface released?

You have a circular reference.
TDatabase contains a reference to TTools and TTools contains a reference to TDatabase.
Because Delphi does not have a garbage collector it is not able to resolve these circular references without help.

If you are using the Mobile NexGen compiler, or D10.1 Berlin the solution is declare TDatabase as:

```
TDatabase = class(TInterfacedObject, IDatabase)
  strict private
    [weak]          <<--
    FTools : ITools;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function Query(AQuery : String) : String;
end;
```

The `[weak]` attribute will trigger Delphi to generate different code when `FTools` is assigned. And the runtime will keep some bookkeeping so that even if the reference count of the interface goes to zero the object will not get destroyed if the weak reference happens to **not** be involved in a circular reference.
Marco Cantù writes about it here: http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2016-april-weak-unsafe-interface-references.html
He also writes about the `[unsafe]` attribute. Don't use that one, unless you know exactly what it means, it's not what you need.

You should only mark one of the circular references as `[weak]`! If you mark both mishaps will occur.

**What to do if the compiler does not support `[weak]`?**
If you are using an older Delphi for the Windows or OSX targets the solution is as follows.

Use this hack as described by: http://blog.dummzeuch.de/2014/06/19/weak-references-or-why-you-should-enable-reportmemoryleaksonshutdown/

> ```
>     procedure SetWeak(_InterfaceField: PIInterface; const _Value: IInterface);
>     begin
>       PPointer(_InterfaceField)^ := Pointer(_Value);
>     end;
>
>     type
>       TChild = class(TInterfacedObject, IChild)
>       private
>         FParent: IParent; // This must be a weak reference!
>       public
>         constructor Create(Parent: IParent);
>         destructor Destroy; override;
>       end;
>
>     constructor TChild.Create(Parent: IParent);
>     begin
>       inherited Create;
>       SetWeak(@FParent, Parent);
>     end;
>
>     destructor TChild.Destroy;
>     begin
>       SetWeak(@FParent, Nil);
>       inherited;
>     end;
> ```

What this does is make a reference in an underhanded way so that the reference count does not go up permanently.
Not that this hack does not have the full protection against mishaps that the `[weak]` attribute gives.
If your weak reference happens to **not** be involved in a circular reference then you might have premature destruction of FParent.

Arnaud Bouchez has a more detailed write-up in his blog; I recommend you read it: http://blog.synopse.info/post/2012/06/18/Circular-reference-and-zeroing-weak-pointers